# SQL Server 2012 Express dying randomly

Tags: sql-server

I have a Windows 2008R2 box with SQL Server 2012 Express. The problem is that randomly (sometimes twice a day, sometimes once a month) the SQL Server dies leaving those messages in error log:

> Error: 49910, Severity: 10, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
>   Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
>   Error: 17312, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.

When I try to start the service again, it says:

> Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
>   Error: 17312, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
>   Error: 33086, Severity: 10, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.

After reboot of the machine it starts working again. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

ERROR 17300 is caused by SQL Server not being able to execute one of the system tasks.
It points to insufficient memory: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280564.aspx

As that resource explains, it could also be caused by a setting, but insufficient memory is more likely the cause.

ERROR 17312 is directly related.

This could be caused by another process eating up all the available memory. For example Windows explorer file copy operations are known to reserve memory and not release it.

Make sure you have adequate memory installed on the system and monitor how much of it is reserved.

Comment: Hmm... I tried running apache benchmark with a lot of requests(ab -n 100000 -c 1000 [IP]) and it didn't kill the server. On that server, there is only IIS and SQL Server. I don't have any idea about what would eat up so much RAM.

Comment: FYI - Express edition can only use a maximum of 1GB memory per instance regardless of what you have on the machine. You can find all the limitations here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx#CrossBoxScale

Comment: OK, but the database is really, really small(about 3000 records, so I don't even know what to look at). And when I was apache benchmarking it(with a 100/100 internet connection), SQL server was using up to 150MB(and there was a lot of free memory).

Comment: The memory is most likely eaten up by a process outside of SQL Server, not by SQL Server itself. Start looking what is going on on the system the next time this happens.